# DJANGO Static Image deletion

Tags: django, web, static

I am experiencing an issue with images saved in the static/images directory in Django. My website was rendering images appropriately, by referencing the name of the image e.g., Image_1. However, once I've tried to delete this image and include a new one in the static/images directory with the same name, Image_1, the website keeps rendering the old image. New images added in the same directory with new names are rendered without issues.

Since then I have specified all STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA and MEDIA_ROOT routes in settings.py, I have run manage.py collectstatic and I have checked the images stored in these directories. The "old" version of Image_1 is not there anymore, but the new one is, and the website still renders the "old" version of it.

Does anybody have an explanation for this, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your settings for static and media files? Is this running locally? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try reset your browser cache "ctrl + f5"

Answer (score 0):

The browser has cached the old image in the PC of browser side .
Close the Page and clear the cache files of the browser,then try again.